# How to connect signal and slot in C++ and Qt and allow a variable to pass to the called slot

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a button in Qt to be able to complete an action.

the class is defined in my browser.h file as below:

```
class MyButtonGroup: public QButtonGroup
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MyButtonGroup(USBDevice dev, QWidget* parent = 0);
        ~ MyButtonGroup(){};
        USBDevice MyDevice;

    public slots:
        //Slot that is called when one of buttons in QButtonGroup is clicked
        void buttonClick(QAbstractButton* button);
    private:
};
```

and in my browser.cpp, I have defined MyButtonGroupClick as below:

```
MyButtonGroup::MyButtonGroup(USBDevice dev, QWidget *parent)
{
    this->setParent(parent);
    this->MyDevice = dev;
    connect(this ,     SIGNAL(buttonClicked(QAbstractButton*)),this,SLOT(buttonClick(QAbstractButton*)));
}
```

and the buttonClick:

```
void MyButtonGroup::buttonClick(QAbstractButton *button)
{
    if (button->text() == "Create Folder") {
        this->MyDevice.CreateNewFolder(this->MyDevice.device_id, "toto", 0, this->MyDevice.device_id->storage->id);
    }
}
```

The class is set the main browser widget app:

```
....
QPushButton* CreateFolderButton = new QPushButton("Create Folder", centralWidget);
CreateFolderButton->setFixedSize(100,20);
QVBoxLayout* Layout = new QVBoxLayout(centralWidget);
Layout->addWidget(CreateFolderButton);

....
MyButtonGroup* group = new MyButtonGroup(MyDevice, centralWidget);
group->addButton(CreateFolderButton);
....
```

It's a first time I'm playing with Qt and also close to be the same with C++.

The issue is that when defining MyButtonGroup::MyButtonGroup, I provide "dev" as argument because I need "dev" data when I'm completing the action "buttonClick"

I think the way I used to pass "dev" through this when I'm doing the connect is not correct and when the api buttonClick is call the this->MyDevice is null and that crash the app.

how to be sure that I can retrieve the parameter I have in the

```
MyButtonGroup::MyButtonGroup(USBDevice dev, QWidget *parent)
```

can be access in

```
MyButtonGroup::buttonClick
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry wrong field. I change the description

Comment: How is MyDevice null? From what I can see it's not a pointer, since you are accessing the `device_id`. Are you sure it's not the `USBDevice::CreateNewFolder` member function that's crashing?

Comment: It's crashing because the MyDevice is not correctly field. What I'm not sure is how to make sure that this->Mydevice = dev in the MyButtonGroup::MyButtonGroup can be used in this->MyDevice.CreateNewFolder(this->MyDevice.device_id in the MyButtonGroup::buttonClick(

Comment: Did you check that `dev` contains the right data?

Comment: Yes it's ok now. The crash was due to a bad definition of my variable and also an issue on the design. Everything is fixed now.